# JavaScript scrollIntoView smooth scroll and offset

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I have this code for my website:

```
function clickMe() {
  var element = document.getElementById('about');
  element.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'start',
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

This works pretty nice but I have a fixed header so when the code scrolls to the element the header is in the way.

Is there a way to have an offset and make it scroll smoothly?

Comment: I fixed this problem by giving the component that scrolls into view some `padding-top`, which acts as the offset.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859042/scrollintoview-with-margin#_=_ use scroll-margin

Answer (score 217, accepted):

> Is there a way to have an offset and make it scroll smoothly?

#Yes, but not with scrollIntoView()

The *scrollIntoViewOptions* of [Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) do **not** allow you to use an offset. It is solely useful when you want to scroll to the **exact** position of the element.

You can however use [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) with options to both scroll to an **offset** position and to do so **smoothly**.

If you have a header with a height of `30px` for example you might do the following:

```
function scrollToTargetAdjusted(){
    var element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
    var headerOffset = 45;
    var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var offsetPosition = elementPosition + window.pageYOffset - headerOffset;
  
    window.scrollTo({
         top: offsetPosition,
         behavior: "smooth"
    });
}
```

This will smoothly scroll to your element just so that it is not blocked from view by your header.

**Note**: You substract the offset because you want to stop before you scroll your header over your element.

#See it in action

You can compare both options in the snippet below.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function scrollToTarget() {

    var element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
    element.scrollIntoView({
      block: "start",
      behavior: "smooth",
    });
  }

  function scrollToTargetAdjusted() {
        var element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
      var headerOffset = 45;
        var elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var offsetPosition = elementPosition + window.pageYOffset - headerOffset;
      
      window.scrollTo({
          top: offsetPosition,
          behavior: "smooth"
      });   
  }

  function backToTop() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }
</script>

<div id="header" style="height:30px; width:100%; position:fixed; background-color:lightblue; text-align:center;"> <b>Fixed Header</b></div>

<div id="mainContent" style="padding:30px 0px;">

  <button type="button" onclick="scrollToTarget();">element.scrollIntoView() smooth, header blocks view</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="scrollToTargetAdjusted();">window.scrollTo() smooth, with offset</button>

  <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
  <div id="targetElement" style="background-color:red;">Target</div>
  <br/>
  <button type="button" onclick="backToTop();">Back to top</button>
  <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
</div>
```

### Edit

`window.pageYOffset` have being added, to fix the problem related to @coreyward comments

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect().top` refers to the distance between the element and the top of the viewport. This is more useful when you're looking to use `scrollBy`, which scrolls relative to the current position, than with `scrollTo`, which is absolute. If the element is not in a relatively positioned parent, consider using `offsetTop` instead. Otherwise, you'll need to add `window.pageYOffset` to `getBoundingClientRect().top` to get the correct value for `scrollTo`.

Comment: This worked for me very well, but to make things simpler, replace headerOffset value (45) with **document.getElementById('header').offsetHeight**. This makes up for any responsive height.

Comment: Your solution does scroll to random locations depending on where the view is right now.

Comment: My container have fixed height 100vh so that I cannot use window scroll and I have to use scrollIntoView however there is a sticky header which is hovering the element it scrolled into. what approach can I take in this case?

Answer (score 103):

**Søren D. Ptæus's** answer got me on the right track but I had issues with `getBoundingClientRect()` when not at the top of the `window`.

My solution adds a bit more to his to get `getBoundingClientRect()` working a bit more consistently with more versatility. I used the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element#11396681) and implemented it to get this working as intended.

```
const element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
const offset = 45;
const bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;
const elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
const elementPosition = elementRect - bodyRect;
const offsetPosition = elementPosition - offset;

window.scrollTo({
  top: offsetPosition,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/ekfuhrmann/pen/pVvpqM)

Remember to include the [polyfill](https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll) when implementing this!

Comment: I hope that your const are defined in the namespace of a function and not globally because it would only calculate distances relatively to your viewport at page loading

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Had the issue with **Søren D. Ptæus** answer either. You had to be at top in order to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for this, I had the same issue since I was using a sticky nav bar, this fixed everything, thanks again!

Comment: This is a very good configurable solution. Customizing the offset especially for smart-headers gives good results.

Answer (score 69):

Simple but elegant solution **if the element has a small height** (shorter than the viewport):

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto' /*or smooth*/, block: 'center' });
```

The `block: center` will scroll the element so the center of the element is at the vertical center of the viewport, so the top header will not cover it.

EDIT 8.5.22: `behavior: instant` was used in the past, but removed from browsers.

Comment: behavior Optional Defines the transition animation. One of auto or smooth. Defaults to auto. Where does the "instant" come from?

Comment: Not sure why this has so many upvotes considering the previous comment is correct about the made-up behavior option. 'instant' does not exist. It's either 'auto' or 'smooth'.

Comment: `instant` was used in the past and  removed by W3C or similar. I will update the answer.

Answer (score 64):

You can use `scrollIntoView()` like in your example

```
function clickMe() {
  var element = document.getElementById('about');
  element.scrollIntoView({
    block: 'start',
    behavior: 'smooth',
  });
}
```

if you add `scroll-margin` with the height of the header to the target element (`about`):

```
.about {
  scroll-margin: 100px;
}
```

Nothing else is needed. `scroll-margin` is [supported by all modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin).

Comment: This is a much simpler solution than the ones above and the best part is, it works!

Comment: This is the best answer - with cleanest solution. Perfect thank you!

Comment: Such a ingenious approach, thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Awesome! So clean.

Comment: this is a better answer than the accepted one. Particularly because one can set the scroll-margin in JS before calling scrollIntoView. Works.

Answer (score 14):

[**Søren D. Ptæus**'s answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49860927/6908282) is almost right, but it only works when the user is on top. This is because getBoundingClientRect will always get us the relative height and using window.scrollTo with a relative height doesn't work.

[**ekfuhrmann**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924496/6908282) improved the answer by getting the total height from the body element and calculating the real height. However, I think it can be easier than that, we can simply use the relative position and use window.scrollBy.

Note: Key difference is window.scrollBy

```js
const HEADER_HEIGHT = 45;

function scrollToTargetAdjusted(){
    const element = document.getElementById('targetElement');
    const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    const offsetPosition = elementPosition - HEADER_HEIGHT;

    window.scrollBy({
         top: offsetPosition,
         behavior: "smooth"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I tried the other solutions, but I was getting some strange behavior. However, this worked for me.

```
function scrollTo(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var headerOffset = 60;
    var elementPosition = element.offsetTop;
    var offsetPosition = elementPosition - headerOffset;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = offsetPosition;
    document.body.scrollTop = offsetPosition; // For Safari
}
```

and the style:

```
html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is a hack and definitely is something that you should use with caution, but you can actually add a `padding` and a negative `margin` to the element. I cannot guarantee that it would work for you as I don't have your markup and code, but I had a similar issue and used this workaround to solve it.

Say your header is `30px` and you want an offset of `15px`, then:

```
  #about {
     padding-top: 45px; // this will allow you to scroll 15px below your 30px header
     margin-top: -45px; // and this will make sure that you don't change your layout because of it
  }
```

Comment: Hack but clever!

Comment: Alternatively you can use `scroll-margin-top: 45px;`

Answer (score 9):

There is also  scroll-margin and scroll-padding.

For me, scroll-padding is most useful for this kind of stuff.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-padding-top
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top

```css
/* Keyword values */
scroll-padding-top: auto;

/* <length> values */
scroll-padding-top: 10px;
scroll-padding-top: 1em;
scroll-padding-top: 10%;

/* Global values */
scroll-padding-top: inherit;
scroll-padding-top: initial;
scroll-padding-top: unset;
```

Additionally, you can use smooth-scroll by setting scroll behaviour to smooth.

```css
/* Keyword values */
scroll-behavior: auto;
scroll-behavior: smooth;

/* Global values */
scroll-behavior: inherit;
scroll-behavior: initial;
scroll-behavior: revert;
scroll-behavior: unset;
```

It's likely not Internet Explorer compatible, though.

Comment: After lot of search, this helped me! Thanks man!

Answer (score 8):

to prevent any element from intersecting with fixed top. there are actually many ways to do that. recently I use scroll-padding-top in CSS file.

```
* {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    scroll-padding-top: 100px; /* this pixel should match fixed header height */
  }
```

what do you mean scroll smoothly?
just add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` in CSS.

if what you want is to open a new page and then scroll smoothly, then that's a different approach. you can check my answer for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73377647/6467902)

if what you looking for is to check if the element is in the viewport or not, then that's another story. I'm not sure which one you are looking for. if it's this one, please confirm and I will spend more time summarizing the answer for you. I had this issue and I finally solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that I wrote based on the [**@ekfuhrmann**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49924496/12320578).
It takes the element that needs to be scrolled to as the first parameter and other options in the form of the object as the second parameter, similar to how the [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) function works.

```
function scrollToTarget(element, options) {
    if (options.headerHeight === undefined) {
        options.headerHeight = 0;
    }

    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    // If an element has 0 height, then it is hidden, do not scroll
    if (elementRect.height == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var offset = elementRect.top - options.headerHeight;

    if (options.block == 'center') {
        // If an element's height is smaller, than the available screen height (without the height of the header), then add the half of the available space
        // to scroll to the center of the screen
        var availableSpace = window.innerHeight - options.headerHeight;
        if (elementRect.height < availableSpace) {
            offset -= (availableSpace - elementRect.height) / 2;
        }
    }

    var optionsToPass = {
        top: offset
    };
    if (options.behavior !== undefined) {
        optionsToPass.behavior = options.behavior
    }

    window.scrollBy(optionsToPass);
}
```

The main difference is that it uses [`window.scrollBy()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollBy) function instead of [`window.scrollTo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), so that we don't need to call [`.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) on `body`.

The `options` parameter can contain a `headerHeight` field - it can contain the height of the fixed element on the screen, that needs to be ignored when scrolling to the element.

This function can also have a `block` option, that for now can only accept a single `"center"` value. When set, the element which is scrolled to will appear in the center of the screen excluding the fixed element height. By default, the scroll will be applied to the element's top.

### Usage example

Here we have two overlapping elements with fixed position. Let's imagine the largest of them is not visible on some viewport widths, so we need to dynamically get the available viewport height minus the height of fixed element.

The following example demonstrates, that the element will appear in the center of the available viewport height if the `block` option is set to `"center"`, similar to how the [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) function works.

```js
function scrollToTarget(element, options) {
    if (options.headerHeight === undefined) {
        options.headerHeight = 0;
    }

    var elementRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (elementRect.height == 0) {
        return;
    }

    var offset = elementRect.top - options.headerHeight;

    if (options.block == 'center') {
        var availableSpace = window.innerHeight - options.headerHeight;
        if (elementRect.height < availableSpace) {
            offset -= (availableSpace - elementRect.height) / 2;
        }
    }

    var optionsToPass = {
        top: offset
    };
    if (options.behavior !== undefined) {
        optionsToPass.behavior = options.behavior
    }

    window.scrollBy(optionsToPass);
}

var headerElements  = [
  document.querySelector('.header__wrap'),
  document.getElementById('wpadminbar')
];
var maxHeaderHeight = headerElements.reduce(function (max, item) {
  return item ? Math.max(max, item.offsetHeight) : max;
}, 0);

document.getElementById('click-me').addEventListener('click', function() {
  scrollToTarget(document.querySelector('.scroll-element'), {
    headerHeight: maxHeaderHeight,
    block: 'center',
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
}
#wpadminbar, .header__wrap {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#wpadminbar {
  height: 32px;
  background-color: #1d2327;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.header__wrap {
  margin: 0 15px;
  height: 74px;
  background-color: #436c50;
  z-index: 1;
}
.scroll-element {
  margin-top: 500px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}
#click-me {
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="wpadminbar"></div>
<div class="header__wrap"></div>
<button id="click-me">Click me!</button>
<!-- Some deeply nested HTML element -->
<div class="scroll-element">
  You scrolled to me and now I am in the visual center of the screen. Nice!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elementRef.current!.scrollIntoView({ 
     behavior: 'smooth', 
     block: 'center' 
})
```

Comment: This only works if nothing exact is needed. A quick, dirty but also often working solution.

Answer (score 0):

**With a very small hack you can make it work with scrollIntoView()**

- Let's say you want to scroll to a section and your elements are in this format:

```html
<section id="about">
 <p>About title</p>
 <p>About description</p>
</section>

<section id="profile">
 <p>About title</p>
 <p>About description</p>
</section>
```

- You convert the above code into this:

```html
<section>
 <span className="section-offset" id="about"></span>
 <!-- or <span className="section-offset" id="about" />  for React -->
 <p>About title</p>
 <p>About description</p>
</section>

<section>
 <span className="section-offset" id="profile"></span>
 <p>Profile title</p>
 <p>Profile description</p>
</section>
```

- Then in your css you can easily change the offset by using:

```css
.section-offset {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 60px; // <<< your offset here >>>
}
```

### Conclusion:

Move the element selector to a span inside the section, then you can use `position: relative` on the span (top/bottom placement does not affect other elements on the page) to set the needed offset. If you need bottom offset, place the `span` element at the end of your section (ex: before the `</section>`).

Answer (score 0):

Come across this question and seems scrollBy provides the best flexibility.  This is just a minimalistic version based on @yangli-io answer to save you some time and cleaner code.

```
function scrollIntoViewAdjusted(elem, offset=0){
  window.scrollBy({
    top: elem.getBoundingClientRect().top - offset,
    behavior: "smooth"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can keep using ***scrollIntoView***, and add css style [**scroll-margin**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin) in your element .
such as

```
.tableClass {
   scroll-margin-top: 52px;
}
```

---

```
tableDom.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', inline: 'start' });
```