# scrollIntoView with margin

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage on which I would like to scroll to a certain element.

That part works fine by using `scrollIntoView`; but I would like to add a bit of space above the element (`20px` or something)

I'm currently doing something like this:

```
const moveToBlue = () => {
  const blue = document.getElementById('blue')
  blue.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'start'});
};
```

I would however like to scroll futher 20px up (see my [demo here](https://codepen.io/methgaard/pen/OvKOpQ))

Is this possible?

Comment: Se following question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665602/scrollintoview-scrolls-just-too-far

Answer (score 199, accepted):

You can set `scroll-margin` CSS property on the scroll target element. For example

```
.blue {
  scroll-margin: 20px;
}
```

(or more specifically `scroll-margin-top` or `scroll-margin-bottom`)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin

Comment: This is what I've been looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: Chrome >= 69, FireFox >= 68 [link](https://caniuse.com/#search=scroll-margin)

Comment: Perfect. In my case, scroll-padding-bottom made sure that scrollIntoView had that buffer in my scrolling element.

Comment: A bit more specific: `scroll-margin-top: 20px;`

Comment: Man you killed it!

Answer (score 8):

You can always use `scrollTo` by first getting the elements coordinates using `getBoundingClientRect` then adding the scroll offset and taking your scroll margin. e.g.

```js
const moveToBlue = () => {
  const blue = document.getElementById('blue');
  let position = blue.getBoundingClientRect();
  // scrolls to 20px above element
  window.scrollTo(position.left, position.top + window.scrollY - 20);
};
```

Comment: Ah this works perfectly for me.  I was using `scrollIntoView` + `scrollMarginTop` but for some reason it didn't apply the margin to the first item in my list. Still not sure why, but using this method works for all cases.

Answer (score 6):

That helped in my case —

HTML

```
<div class='stick-to-top'></>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('stick-to-top')[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "center"});
```

CSS

```
.stick-to-top {
 padding-bottom: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In general it's not very straightforward (if we want `behavior: smooth`), and will require messing with javascript in one way or another. For example you could use [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) and calculate necessary top position manually.

In some cases however you could visually achieve necessary effect by using CSS smartly. In your demo you can use `padding-top` instead of margin and wrap content of the block into additional helper container.

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OvKQLV

Comment: Better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59611245/13331155

Answer (score 3):

Another potential solution is to scroll not the the element itself, but to one of its previous siblings. Example:

```js
let elementToScrollTo = <yourTargetElement>;
const childOffset = 3;
for (let i = 0; i < childOffset; i++) {
    if (!elementToScrollTo.previousElementSibling) {
       break;
    }
    elementToScrollTo = elementToScrollTo.previousElementSibling;
}
elementToScrollTo.scrollIntoView();
```