# CSS what does scroll-margin do

Tags: css, scroll, scrollbar

**TL; DR: What does CSS scroll-margin do?**

I wanted to scroll to the bottom of my chat box. I used scrollIntoView with a dummy div, but it was 8px off because of my box's 8px of bottom padding. I read [scrollIntoView with margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49859042/scrollintoview-with-margin) and I used scroll-margin and it worked like a charm, but now I am wondering why. The docs say that scroll-margin is for defining a scroll snap area, but when I used it, I didn't get anything like a snap area.

CSS snippets:

```
.chat-messages-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0 8px 8px 8px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.chat-scroll-dummy {
  scroll-margin: 8px;
}
```

JS

```
dummyEle.scrollIntoView();
```

To clarify, I got the desired outcome, and now I am wondering why.