# scrollIntoView() with fixed header

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollview

This is probably a simple question but I need some help.

I have this code:

```
var lastitem='';
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion> dd').hide();

$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function() {
    allPanels.slideUp();
    if ($(this).text() != lastitem) {
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
        lastitem = $(this).text();
        $(this).get(0).scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
            block: "start" // or "end"
        });
    } else {
        lastitem = '';
    };
    return false;
  });

})(jQuery);
```

And I have a fixed header, so when I click on the accordion it scrolls into viewport, the problem is my fixed header. I would need to scroll into viewport + 100px from top.

Something like:

```
$(this).get(0).scrollIntoView({
    behavior: "smooth", // or "auto" or "instant"
    block: "start + 100px" // or "end"
});
```

That's all, any suggestion? thank you!!

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820013/javascript-scroliintoview-smooth-scroll-and-offset

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript scrolIintoview smooth scroll and offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820013/javascript-scroliintoview-smooth-scroll-and-offset)

Answer (score 2):

From what I have read from the specification on [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView), you cannot offset on the block.