# ScrollIntoView 20px above element?

Tags: javascript, scroll

let's say I have the follwing function:

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target) {
  var scrollContainer = target;
  scrollContainer.scrollIntoView(true);
}
```

How can I make the page scroll 20px above the element instead of scrolling to the element itself?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit due to CSS getting updated**

Use [`scroll-margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top), introduced after the original answer was written.

**Original 2018 answer**

Get the dimensional information for your element and then rather than scrolling it into view, tell the window to scroll to your element's `top` minus 20:

```
function scrollToJustAbove(element, margin=20) {
  let dims = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, dims.top - margin);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. but instead of the getBoundingClientRect() I used .offsetTop which seemed to work fine.

Comment: It only _seems_ to work fine, but the offsetX/Y properties are _relative_ values, measured with respect to the parent's bounds. If your intention is reliable scroll, based on where the element _actually is_, then don't make that change, and stick with `getBoundingClientRect` =)

Comment: There's a more fully fleshed out answer/demo for this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820013/javascript-scrollintoview-smooth-scroll-and-offset

Comment: For anyone that will use this answer, keep in mind that it work only when using the window scrollbar and similar cases. If you use it in a content inside a popup/popper, for example, it won't work.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: @WaleedAhmad "it doesn't work" is just as useless in a comment as it is in a question post, because it doesn't tell anyone anything. The `window.scrollTo` function [guaranteed works in your browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollTo), provided you're not using a dead browser like IE.

Comment: Use CSS `scroll-margin-top`

Comment: Indeed. Answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

If you are scrolling to a target from a non-fixed position on the page (say, from a sticky navigation bar) you have to take into account the current position that you're scrolling from. To do this, add window. scrollY to the y number in scrollTo (borrowing Mike's code):

```
function scrollToJustAbove(element, margin=20) {
   let dims = element.getBoundingClientRect();
   window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, dims.top - margin + window.scrollY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also add a negative margin-top and the same amount of padding-top. For example:

```
.element {
  margin-top:-20px;
  padding-top:20px;
}
```

or even better

```
.element {
  scroll-margin-top: 45px;
}
```

Comment: `scroll-margin-top` is the proper solution for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well, for smooth scroll you can use jQuery `animate()`. Check the code below:

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target, above, speed) {
  let $scrollContainer = $target;
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: jQuery(scrollContainer).offset().top - above
  }, speed);
}
```

[Note: `above` will be your 20 (as you wanted 20px above the target), `speed` will be any number say: 900 like that.]

If it helps...!

Answer (score -3):

Please change variables definations.
$scrollContainer and target vars are not same, you can use at below

```
window.smoothScroll = function(target, above, speed) {
    let scrollContainer = target;
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(scrollContainer).offset().top - above
    }, speed);}
```