# HTML - # to move to the specific part of the page + some number of pixels

Tags: javascript, html

I use the following code to move (after the user click) to the specific part of the page:

```html
<a class="text-link font-weight-bold" href="#employees">See the list of employees</a>
```

So the table in the bottom of my page looks like this:

```html
<table id="employees" ...>
...
</table>
```

However, this always moves the user so that he can't see the top of the table, until he scrolls a bit. Is there any way to say that I want to move to this table and add `x` pixels to that distance?

Comment: Could you get away with a negative margin on #employees ?

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49820013/javascript-scrollintoview-smooth-scroll-and-offset) I think it might be able to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: You can just add additional padding/margin on top to move your content to be visible. Or possible create a container and add the padding/margin on it.